# Accessing Frame Buffer

Tags: android, framebuffer, android-binder

I am trying to find energy consumption of AMOLED displays and therefore, want to detect changes in the frame buffer of an Android phone at runtime.

I read that Android framework used SurfaceManager library to combine, construct, and project the frames onto the screen. Also, SurfaceManager uses Android Binder to manage the frame buffer in the Linux kernel.

My question is, how exactly can I access the frame buffer with the help of SurfaceManager and Android Binder, through Linux?